# Converting HTML5 to XHTML

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-eleven, html5

What do I need to ponder if I want to convert Twenty Eleven theme to XHTML? Is it just the matter of replacing the HTML5 for divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to set the doctype, etc and then use the w3c xhtml validator and just go through one by one and pick off the errors...but that will take A LOT of time, I strongly recommend you leave it as is.

Comment: Since the style is ruled by CSS, if you convert HTML5 to XHTML, the output should be the same, right?

Comment: Yes and no, if you have an `<aside>` element and you convert it to a `<div>`, the css will still read `aside {blah}`, and you'll need to apply a class to the div to be able to target it like that. The whole idea of HTML5 is that it adds additional elements, etc to make your HTML read more semantically